# ffmpeg playout rtmp stream continuously when rtmp stream lost for few seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create an rtmp player that receives the stream from the server and displays it on the "Decklink mini monitor"
this is my command

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 32768 -i rtmp://myserver/live/rahim -bufsize 5000k -preset ultrafast -async 1 -vsync -1 -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -r 50000/1000 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt uyvy422 -f decklink 'DeckLink Mini Monitor'
```

Everything is fine

but !!!
ffmpeg can not continue when the stream is disconnected and reconnected for any reason and ffmpeg output is:

```
[flv @ 0x55b1c4d76d40] DTS 0 < 7258 out of order6.90 bitrate=N/A speed=1.13x
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!x
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!360 speed=0.506x
    Last message repeated 2 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 7 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 5 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!362 speed=0.516x
    Last message repeated 9 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 5 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 3 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 6 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 9 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 6 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 1 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 4 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!362 speed=0.554x
    Last message repeated 2 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 7 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 6 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!362 speed=0.564x
    Last message repeated 9 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
    Last message repeated 7 times
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
[decklink @ 0x55b1c4d8aec0] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
Last message repeated 8 times
```

Does anyone have a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can create a batch file:

```
:START
ffmpeg ... <here is your command>
if errorlevel 1 goto START
```

That code should auto-restart your command if there was any error.